# MOZREPL output showing up in terminal window

Tags: debian, terminal, perl, tty

I have a very a annoying problem. I've using Mac Terminal over SSH to write Perl script with vim on a local virtual Debian machine. The Perl script uses the [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.78/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm) module which in turn uses the [`MozRepl::RemoteObject`](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/MozRepl-RemoteObject-0.39/lib/MozRepl/RemoteObject.pm) object module.

The problem I'm having is that output from `MozRepl` is showing up in another terminal window on another tty every time I run the script, making it a mess:

[image: Screenshot showing output of MozRepl in terminal window]

I have to close out the vim session and reopen it to clear the garbage from the terminal.

I don't want to completely suppress the output of the script because I need it to print debug statements. I just want to stop the output from `MozRepl` from showing up in my terminal window.

I tried setting `log => ['fatal']` when creating the W:M:F object but it had no effect.

Comment: perhaps the terminal being overwritten is the one in which you first ran firefox?

Comment: I believe that they tty terminal the output is appearing on is the same tty terminal the X server is running on.